# Generating ECPublicKey from X,Y parameters in C#

Tags: c#, cryptography

Im trying to port security code implemented in java to C#. 
In java spongycastle was used so i used the equivalent bouncy castle for c# but i couldn't get the equivalent implementation in .Net for following library files which are used in the sample code mentioned below. can someone point me to right library files in bounty castle for c# or in .Net

```
import java.security.interfaces.ECPrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.ECPublicKey;
import java.security.spec.ECParameterSpec;
import java.security.spec.ECPoint;
import java.security.spec.ECPublicKeySpec;

All i'm using in these files is 

public static ECPublicKey createECPublicKeyFromXY(ECParameterSpec paramtrs,      final byte[] pubkey)
{
    int keySizeBytes = paramtrs.getOrder().bitLength() / Byte.SIZE;

    int offset = 1;
    BigInteger x = new BigInteger(1, Arrays.copyOfRange(pubkey, offset,
            offset + keySizeBytes));

    offset += keySizeBytes;
    BigInteger y = new BigInteger(1, Arrays.copyOfRange(pubkey, offset,
           offset + keySizeBytes));

    ECPoint w = new ECPoint(x, y);

    ECPublicKeySpec otherKeySpec = new ECPublicKeySpec(w, paramtrs);

    try {
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDH", "SC");
        return (ECPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(otherKeySpec);

    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you try in C# / BC that didn't work, and why didn't it work? Be specific, Bob.

Comment: this is a java code using java security library and i need to convert this function into c# using bountycastle library as my intended application is in C#                                                                                                         import java.security.interfaces.ECPrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.ECPublicKey;
import java.security.spec.ECParameterSpec;
import java.security.spec.ECPoint;
import java.security.spec.ECPublicKeySpec;